# Вывод лайков у всех

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести кол-во записей с таблицы `likes` ко всем записям таблицы `highlights` то есть у меня есть таблица: Likes и таблица highlights мне нужно что бы к записям из таблицы highlights выводились кол-во лайков у всех.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в Likes есть колонка типа id_highlights, хранящая ID записи в Likes, для которой оставлен "лайк", то

```
SELECT data FROM Likes WHERE id_highlights = 'ID, для которого нужно полцчить данные по лайкам'
```

Comment: Не верно, т.к у меня страница видеозаписей (videos.php) на ней так как на скрине таблицей, то есть очень много, я не определенного видео хочу лайки вывести а всех.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сумму всех лайков для всех видеозаписей на странице? Или для каждой видяхи отдельный лайк (например, 30 видях - 30 счетчиков лайков?

Comment: именно так